# Query a database 'within this week' for date

Tags: php, mysql, case, increment

I want to use the following query:

```
SELECT concat(firstname,' ', surname) AS 'Fname', 
MAX(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(date) = 1 THEN concat(starttime,'-', endtime) END) `Sunday`,
MAX(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(date) = 2 THEN concat(starttime,'-', endtime) END) `Monday`,
MAX(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(date) = 3 THEN concat(starttime,'-', endtime)  END) `Tuesday`,
MAX(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(date) = 4 THEN concat(starttime,'-', endtime)  END) `Wednesday`,
MAX(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(date) = 5 THEN concat(starttime,'-', endtime)  END) `Thursday`,
MAX(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(date) = 6 THEN concat(starttime,'-', endtime)  END) `Friday`,
MAX(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(date) = 7 THEN concat(starttime,'-', endtime)  END) `Saturday`
FROM shifts NATURAL JOIN employees
GROUP BY Fname, date
```

And somehow modify it to display only THIS WEEKS values, something like this:

```
SELECT concat(firstname,' ', surname) AS 'Fname', 
MAX(CASE WHEN (DAYOFWEEK(date) = 1 AND WITHIN THIS WEEK) THEN concat(starttime,'-', endtime) END) `Sunday`,
etc... etc...
```

Is this possible through mySQL?

Comment: Have you considered how a BETWEEN statement works?

Answer (score 0):

The question is: which week are you talking about? I would use the where criteria part of the select statement to filter for the period, however, you need to define which is the week you are talkin about.

1. Use between ... and ... if you know the exact start and end dates of the week:

   ... where date between ... and ...
2. Use [week()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) (or weekofyear()) and year() functions to get dates for a single week (pls note that starting day of a week is a configurable variable, see the link for week() for details):

   ... where year(date)=... and week(date)=...
3. Same logic as in the previous, just use [date_format()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to get the year and week combination.